# Run source after Ubuntu starts

Tags: cron, startup, autostart, source

I need to run the command

`source "/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh"` after Ubuntu starts. It's taken from [here](https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/). It updated `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH` etc.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/13394), but doesn't work. After system starts `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourcing a command will affect your current shell environment. Running this from `crontab` wont work. Put it in your `.bashrc` instead. This is also what the tutorial says:

> `Add the below line in **.profile** or **.bashrc**`

```bsh
# Add the below line in **.profile** or **.bashrc**
## This will load all the needed environmental variables for SQLanywhere17
source "/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh"
```

Run:

```bsh
echo 'source "/opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/sa_config.sh"' >> "~/.bashrc"
```

and restart your terminal.